# .htaccess Redirect all routes to .html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server, httpd.conf

I would like to redirect all routes to route_name.html file.
For example,

```
https://example.com/blah
```

to

```
https://example.com/blah.html
```

I also would like to remove tailing slash from all urls to non slash to connect with the above redirect rule.

Comment: "redirect all routes to `route_name.html`" - But your example goes to `blah.html`? - So basically you want extensionless URLs? Presumably you mean "rewrite", not "redirect"?

Answer (score 1):

something like this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ /$1.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /$1.html [NC]
```

Comment: This doesn't match the example URL stated in the question (ie. `/blah`). It also doesn't _remove_ the trailing slash on the URL.

Comment: updated, works now for both trailing slash and without trailing slash

Comment: Unfortunately, this would now result in a rewrite loop (500 error) because the 2nd rule runs unconditionally and repeatedly appends `.html` to the URL-path.

Comment: No I already verified it works exactly as requested by the original question poster